# CSRF protection for Django and Angular application

Tags: django, django-csrf

I have an application with Django in backend and Angular in frontend. I am serving the application through Django. I want to write an API in django to perform edit on Angular form. For now I have written the API using @csrf exempt decorator on top of the view. But now I want to remove @csrf exempt decorator and want to protect it from csrf.

How to proceed for this.

Comment: what kind of authorization do you use in your app? is it cookie-based?

Comment: yes authorization is based on cookie